# How to calculate whether a point is in a shape using geodetic calculations

Tags: geotools, point-in-polygon

I’m new to GIS so forgive me if my terminology isn’t completely correct.  Really liking the options available in the GeoTools library but I’ve hit a stumbling block that I’m hoping someone will be able to advise on.  I’ve looked at the classes in the library but can’t find a method that is giving me what I need.  I have a scenario where I have a point and a polygon defined by latitude and longitude (WGS84).  I need to determine whether the point is in (or on the boundary) of the polygon.

I have tried using the Intersects method but it looks to be treating the polygon as if it is on a 2D plane.  The bottom left and right corners of my polygon have the same latitude value but they are spaced longitudinally by 10 degrees, so it’s quite a long edge.  There are no intermediate points along this edge of the polygon.  The Intersects method appears to use a straight line between these two points, effectively taking this bottom edge under ground when on a globe.

What I need is for this polygon’s edges to be interpreted as great circle lines between points on the surface of the globe, thereby creating slight curves, so when we determine whether a point is in the polygon, we are using the shape with slightly curved edges.  Obviously the greater distance between polygon points the greater the curve.

Is there a method to achieve this in the GeoTools library?  If not, does anyone have alternative open source Java libraries that can solve what must be a common request?

Comment: A closed curve on a sphere divides the sphere into two regions, so unless you have a way of determining which is "inside" and which is "outside" your question is meaningless. For example you might define "inside" as the smaller of the two regions, or the region containing a given point.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [JTS Densifier](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/densify/Densifier.html) which takes a geometry and returns the same line but with more points in it.

```
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    LineString l = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(-10, 50),new Coordinate(10, 50)});
    WKTWriter2 writer = new WKTWriter2();
    System.out.println(writer.writeFormatted(l));
    LineString dl = (LineString) Densifier.densify(l, 1);
    System.out.println(writer.writeFormatted(dl));
```

Which gives you the following:

```
LINESTRING (-10 50, 10 50)
LINESTRING (-10 50, -9.047619047619047 50, -8.095238095238095 50, -7.142857142857143 50, -6.190476190476191 50, -5.238095238095238 50, -4.2857142857142865 50, -3.333333333333334 50, -2.3809523809523814 50, -1.4285714285714288 50, -0.4761904761904763 50, 0.4761904761904763 50, 1.428571428571427 50, 2.3809523809523796 50, 3.333333333333332 50, 4.285714285714285 50, 5.238095238095237 50, 6.19047619047619 50, 7.142857142857142 50, 8.095238095238095 50, 9.047619047619047 50, 10 50)
```

How these appear on your map will depend on your projection, if you are using a plate carree projection (e.g 4326) then they are identical if however you use a Transverse Mercator like OSGB (27700) the 2nd one is curved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.  If we take the example above, the generated points using the densify method all have a latitude of 50, but the shortest line over the globe between the two end points doesn't follow this path.  I'm after calculating whether the point is in a shape with edges following the shortest path between two points based on the great circle distance.

Comment: may be you need to add an actual polygon and point to your question

Comment: Thanks.  The actual polygon has the following WGS84 lat/long:55°00'00", -006°00'00"
55°00'00", 005°00'00"
57°00'00", 005°00'00"
57°00'00", -006°00'00" and the point WGS84 lat/long is 55.1067974034583, -1.41499006215356.Just looking at the lat value of the point, being greater than 55deg, my instinct is to take this as being inside the polygon.  However, the great circle line between the polygon's bottom two points creates an upward curve and doesn't follow the 55deg parallel and this upward curve sends my point outside of the shape.  Very confused - probably due to my inexperience with GIS

Comment: it is clearly inside the polygon

Comment: If we took the map above as an example.  If the straight line at 50N defined the northernmost edge of a polygon, and we had a point positioned at Lands End (i.e. below the straight line and slightly above the curve) then would you say the point was inside or outside the polygon?  It would have a latitude less than 50N so instinct says it is in the polygon, but if we look at the latitudes along the curve in that area,they are all below Lands End, suggesting our point would fall outside the polygon. On a globe, without applying a projection, is there no way to decide if a point is in a shape?

Comment: that is why you need to densify before you reproject

Comment: Thanks Ian. I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. Can I check my understanding: Densify will create new points all having latitude 50N. They can appear as a straight line or curve on a 2D map depending on the projection selected. This works fine if the polygon edge between the start and end 50N points should follow the parallel. But am I correct in thinking that this path isn't necessarily the path of minimum distance between the two points?  If I'm right, then I'm after is a point in polygon method that uses the path of shortest distance between points to define the polygon edge.

Comment: in the GIS world we (nearly) always join points with straight lines, when moving from a curved reference plane (lat/lon) to a flat one (a map) this can cause distortion. The more points in your line the more likely it is to represent a good approximation of the line. Also remember your point will move with the line when reprojected.

Comment: The basic thing to remember is that when dealing with this you should reproject to a cartesian frame or local projection. Then JTS (& GeoTools) will handle the point in polygon for you as expected. It may look odd though when you draw it out.